# Why are my datastore Writes per Entity Group per Second far over the stated limit?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I'm updating an entity with objectify inside a transaction. My guess was that I can only write to the same entity group around 1 to 5 times per second. This would conform to the documentation and advices around writing into the datastore. But after running some simple load tests on the following code, I saw

- around 90 writes per second on a single entity
- around 50 writes per second on random entities in the same entity group.

Why is this possible? Where is my mistake?

```
// text => a random text, different for each request
public void update(final Key<SomeEntity> toLoad, String text) {
    final AtomicInteger attempts = new AtomicInteger(0);

    SomeEntity modified = ofy().transact(new Work<SomeEntity>() {
        public SomeEntity run() {
            // count every attempt
            attempts.incrementAndGet();

            SomeEntity toModify = ofy().load().key(toLoad).now();
            if (toModify != null) {

                // modifies the entity
                toModify.setText(text);

                ofy().save().entity(toModify).now();
            }

            return toModify;
        }
    });

    if (attempts.get() > 1) {
        logger.warning(attempts.get() + " attempts for update on " + modified);
    }
}
```

In the Cloud Console Log Viewer a lot of retries are reported, most warnings had ~ 2 attempts, some transactions had 5 attempts, but were executed and updated the entity. Are there any special strategies for load tests on GAE? Or any general advice on this topic?

**Update:**

A short description of the entity group structure and test setup. To make it easy to select an entity the key name reflects the entity's position in it's entity group. "001-001-100" is a 2nd level entity in the entity group with the root entity "100" and has the parent "001-100". So an entity group looks like this:

```
- 100
  - 001-100
    - 001-001-100
    - 002-001-100
    - 003-001-100
    - ...
  - 002-100
  - 003-100
  - 004-100
  - 005-100
  - ...
- 101
- ...
```

I tried three different version. Each one is using another value for the update request in JMeter. All update exactly the same entity "001-001-100".

```
// Version A: text does not change during load test
vars.put("text", "Foo Bar");

// Version B: text changes every second during load test
var d = new Date();
vars.put("text", [d.getHours(), d.getMinutes(), d.getSeconds()].join("-")));

// Version B: text changes every request
vars.put("text", Math.random());
```

- Version A: ~ 110 requests / second
- Version B: ~ 70 requests / second
- Version C: ~ 24 requests / second

But still: 24 writes on one entity per second is really high. So I slightly redesigned the test.

Then I modified the test slightly. Instead of firing requests on only one entity, I now distribute them over the 2nd level of an entity group. So JMeter uses randomly "001-001-100", "002-001-100", "003-001-100", "004-001-100", or "005-001-100". More or less the same result as if I choose only one entity.

- Version A: ~ 110 requests / second
- Version B: ~ 100 requests / second
- Version C: ~ 20 requests / second

**Update 2:**
If you execute the load test with just one single thread, the throughput is around 2.5 updates per second. This is closer to the proposed limit. If I run the test with 80 threads, the throughput goes up to the numbers I posted before. The response times for the samples are not the best, but the throughput keeps high: avg = 2100ms, median = 1350ms, 90% = 5400ms, max = 18000ms. Maybe the throughput might not be a gut measure for the datastore limits?

Comment: Are you actually modifying an entity, i.e. set a different text every time?

Comment: Yes, the text is randomly generated by JMeter and the changes are visible if I load the entity during the load test.

Comment: This is hard to answer without a more complete test. My advice would be to wrap it up in a minimal github project and invite people to take a look.

Comment: Here the code for this example:
https://gist.github.com/botic/7885fe0266ad0f97c99f

Answer (score 1):

1. You get the benefits of entity caching (versions A and B). It may be at Objectify's level, or within the Datastore's infrastructure.
2. 5 requests per second is not a hard limit. It's a warning:

> Writes to a single entity group are serialized by the App Engine
>   datastore, and thus there's a limit on how quickly you can update one
>   entity group. In general, this works out to somewhere between 1 and 5
>   updates per second; a good guideline is that you should consider
>   rearchitecting if you expect an entity group to have to sustain more
>   than one update per second for an extended period.

Note that:

(a) A simple text string has almost no serialization overhead. It will not be the case with a complex entity.

(b) The warning includes the words "extended period".

Comment: In version A and B the cache should not help since Objectify's global cache is not used and the session cache only stores the entities from the read, but still has to update it inside the transaction which requires a low-level datastore write. The session cache is per Objectify instance, so two separate requests will not share the same cache.

Thanks for the hint with the simple text serialization. It would be interesting to repeat this with a more complex entity.